# Drop Down Menu and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have a drop down menu to show different Google Maps. The Dining map shows up, but when I switch to another map, like say Parks, it shows a gray box with the marker icon on the top left corner, and you see a 1 second view/flash of another map underneath it. It works when I put "visible" in each "neighborhood-listing" class, but then there's multiple maps showing at the same time rather than only one.

HTML

```
   <div class="explore">
    <h4>Explore Your New Neighborhood</h4>
    <select id="neighborhood-select">
      <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
      <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
      <option value="Schools">Schools</option>
      <option value="Parks">Parks</option>
      <option value="Hospitals">Hospitals</option>
      <option value="Colleges">Colleges</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="explore-images featured-image">
    <div class="neighborhood-listing Dining visible">
      <div class="neighborhood-btns">
       <div id="map-dining"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="neighborhood-listing Shopping ">
      <div class="neighborhood-btns">
        <div id="map-shopping"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="neighborhood-listing Parks ">
      <div class="neighborhood-btns">
        <div id="map-parks"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="neighborhood-listing Hospitals ">
      <div class="neighborhood-btns">
        <div id="map-hospitals"></div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="neighborhood-listing Colleges ">
      <div class="neighborhood-btns">
        <div id="map-colleges"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="neighborhood-listing Schools ">
      <div class="neighborhood-btns"> 
      <div id="map-schools"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing,
.explore-images .leasing-plan {
display: none;
}
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing.visible,
.explore-images .leasing-plan.visible {
display: block;
}

.explore {
padding: 2.5% 5%;
background-color: #f2efef;
}
.explore h4 {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: .5em;
}

/* .directory-btns, */
.neighborhood-btns {
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.desktop {
    display: none;
}
.mobile {
    display: block;
}
}

#map-dining, #map-shopping, #map-schools, #map-parks, #map-hospitals, #map-colleges{
width:100%;
height: 400px;
}
```

I am hoping to have each map show up properly (like "Dining") when selected from the drop-down menu and prevent the 1 second view of another map (during transition) from occurring, basically have it smoothly transition to the next selected map.

Link to [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sf82/fbt9p701/1/).

---

***SOLVED***

I really like the smooth transition of Godwin's jsfiddle, only if the resizing was as smooth! I also really like how geocode zip's jsfiddle worked, the resizing was perfect! It was just the transition wasn't as smooth since it still had the beige box view with the marker on the top left during transition. So what I did was sort of combine the two codes, and it pretty much was what I was looking for. Thank you all so much, I'm really grateful for all your help!

Edited JS Fiddle with working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/sf82/fbt9p701/1/

CSS changed:

```
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing,
.explore-images .leasing-plan {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing.visible,
.explore-images .leasing-plan.visible {
    display: block;         
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JS added:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#leasing-select, #neighborhood-select, #store-directories-select').change(function () {
    var new_image = $(this).val();
    $('.explore-images .visible').fadeOut().removeClass('visible');
    $('.explore-images .' + new_image).fadeIn(function () {
        resizeMap(new_image);
    }).addClass('visible');

});
});

function resizeMap(type) {
var typeL = type.toLowerCase();
switch (typeL) {
    case 'dining':
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        break;
    case 'shopping':
        google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
        map2.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        break;
    case 'schools':
        google.maps.event.trigger(map3, 'resize');
        map3.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        break;
    case 'parks':
        google.maps.event.trigger(map4, 'resize');
        map4.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        break;
    case 'hospitals':
        google.maps.event.trigger(map5, 'resize');
        map5.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        break;
    case 'colleges':
        google.maps.event.trigger(map6, 'resize');
        map6.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps won't render properly if the target element is `display: none`. You can get around this by using the `visibility` and `position: absolute` properties instead: http://jsfiddle.net/dd8q234b/7/. This still has issues on resize however.

```
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing,
.explore-images .leasing-plan {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing.visible,
.explore-images .leasing-plan.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

A better solution would probably be to use the same map but reset the markers when the selection changes: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Answer (score 0):

Are you switching classes at the divs to make them visible/invisible?

I had the same problem and I figured out that the map doesn't render properly if loaded in an invisible element.
I solved the problem by initializing the map AFTER showing the div, so you could trying to init the map when you switch classes (or whatever you do to make the divs visible/invisible).

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the 'resize' event on the map that is being displayed after it has been displayed, then reset the center of the map:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#leasing-select, #neighborhood-select, #store-directories-select').change(function () {
        var new_image = $(this).val();
        $('.explore-images .visible').fadeOut().removeClass('visible');
        $('.explore-images .' + new_image).fadeIn(function () {
            resizeMap(new_image);
        }).addClass('visible');

    });
});

function resizeMap(type) {
    var typeL = type.toLowerCase();
    switch (typeL) {
        case 'dining':
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
            break;
        case 'shopping':
            google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
            map2.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
            break;
        case 'schools':
            google.maps.event.trigger(map3, 'resize');
            map3.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
            break;
        case 'parks':
            google.maps.event.trigger(map4, 'resize');
            map4.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
            break;
        case 'hospitals':
            google.maps.event.trigger(map5, 'resize');
            map5.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
            break;
        case 'colleges':
            google.maps.event.trigger(map6, 'resize');
            map6.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dd8q234b/13/)

**note:** I had to remove the local definition of the "map" variables from inside the `initialize` function and remove your "map resize" event listener.

**code snippet:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#leasing-select, #neighborhood-select, #store-directories-select').change(function() {
    var new_image = $(this).val();
    $('.explore-images .visible').fadeOut().removeClass('visible');
    $('.explore-images .' + new_image).fadeIn(function() {
      resizeMap(new_image);
    }).addClass('visible');

  });
});

function resizeMap(type) {
  var typeL = type.toLowerCase();
  switch (typeL) {
    case 'dining':
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
      break;
    case 'shopping':
      google.maps.event.trigger(map2, 'resize');
      map2.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
      break;
    case 'schools':
      google.maps.event.trigger(map3, 'resize');
      map3.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
      break;
    case 'parks':
      google.maps.event.trigger(map4, 'resize');
      map4.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
      break;
    case 'hospitals':
      google.maps.event.trigger(map5, 'resize');
      map5.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
      break;
    case 'colleges':
      google.maps.event.trigger(map6, 'resize');
      map6.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

var map, map2, map3, map4, map5, map6;
var mapOptions;

function initialize() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(39.458342, -74.633672);


  var locations = [
    ['Cavallino Nero', 39.456832, -74.660559, 2],
    ['IHOP', 39.453284, -74.651666, 3],
    ['Longhorn Steakhouse', 39.453224, -74.641467, 4],
    ['Chilis Grill and Bar', 39.450375, -74.639798, 5],
    ['Applebees', 39.452392, -74.631073, 6]
  ];

  var locationsA = [
    ['Cavallino Nero', 39.456832, -74.660559, 2],
    ['IHOP', 39.453284, -74.651666, 3],
    ['Longhorn Steakhouse', 39.453224, -74.651666, 4],
    ['Chilis Grill and Bar', 39.450375, -74.639798, 5],
    ['Applebees', 39.452392, -74.631073, 6]
  ];

  var locationsB = [
    ['Cavallino Nero', 39.456832, -74.660559, 2],
    ['IHOP', 39.453284, -74.651666, 3],
    ['Longhorn Steakhouse', 39.453224, -74.651666, 4],
    ['Chilis Grill and Bar', 39.450375, -74.639798, 5],
    ['Applebees', 39.452392, -74.631073, 6]
  ];

  var locationsC = [
    ['Cavallino Nero', 39.456832, -74.660559, 2],
    ['IHOP', 39.453284, -74.651666, 3],
    ['Longhorn Steakhouse', 39.453224, -74.651666, 4],
    ['Chilis Grill and Bar', 39.450375, -74.639798, 5],
    ['Applebees', 39.452392, -74.631073, 6]
  ];

  var locationsD = [
    ['Cavallino Nero', 39.456832, -74.660559, 2],
    ['IHOP', 39.453284, -74.651666, 3],
    ['Longhorn Steakhouse', 39.453224, -74.651666, 4],
    ['Chilis Grill and Bar', 39.450375, -74.639798, 5],
    ['Applebees', 39.452392, -74.631073, 6]
  ];

  var locationsE = [
    ['Cavallino Nero', 39.456832, -74.660559, 2],
    ['IHOP', 39.453284, -74.651666, 3],
    ['Longhorn Steakhouse', 39.453224, -74.651666, 4],
    ['Chilis Grill and Bar', 39.450375, -74.639798, 5],
    ['Applebees', 39.452392, -74.631073, 6]
  ];

  mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.458342, -74.633672),
    zoom: 13
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-dining"), mapOptions);
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-shopping"), mapOptions);
  map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-schools"), mapOptions);
  map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-parks"), mapOptions);
  map5 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-hospitals"), mapOptions);
  map6 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-colleges"), mapOptions);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, markerA, markerB, markerC, markerC, markerD, markerE, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/restaurant.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < locationsA.length; i++) {
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsA[i][1], locationsA[i][2]),
      map: map2,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/purple-dot.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', (function(markerA, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locationsA[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map2, markerA);
      }
    })(markerA, i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < locationsB.length; i++) {
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsB[i][1], locationsB[i][2]),
      map: map3,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'click', (function(markerB, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locationsB[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map3, markerB);
      }
    })(markerB, i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < locationsC.length; i++) {
    markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsC[i][1], locationsC[i][2]),
      map: map4,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/tree.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerC, 'click', (function(markerC, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locationsC[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map4, markerC);
      }
    })(markerC, i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < locationsD.length; i++) {
    markerD = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsD[i][1], locationsD[i][2]),
      map: map5,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerD, 'click', (function(markerD, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locationsD[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map5, markerD);
      }
    })(markerD, i));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < locationsE.length; i++) {
    markerE = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsE[i][1], locationsE[i][2]),
      map: map6,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_whiteA.png'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerE, 'click', (function(markerE, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locationsE[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map6, markerE);
      }
    })(markerE, i));
  }

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map,
    title: "Evergreen"
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map2,
    title: "Evergreen"
  });
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map3,
    title: "Evergreen"
  });
  var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map4,
    title: "Evergreen"
  });
  var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map5,
    title: "Evergreen"
  });
  var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    map: map6,
    title: "Evergreen"
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing,
.explore-images .leasing-plan {
  display: none;
}
.explore-images .neighborhood-listing.visible,
.explore-images .leasing-plan.visible {
  display: block;
}
.explore {
  padding: 2.5% 5%;
  background-color: #f2efef;
}
.explore h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
/* .directory-btns, */

.neighborhood-btns {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
#map-dining,
#map-shopping,
#map-schools,
#map-parks,
#map-hospitals,
#map-colleges {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="explore">
  <h4>Explore Your New Neighborhood</h4>

  <select id="neighborhood-select">
    <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
    <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
    <option value="Schools">Schools</option>
    <option value="Parks">Parks</option>
    <option value="Hospitals">Hospitals</option>
    <option value="Colleges">Colleges</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="explore-images featured-image">
  <div class="neighborhood-listing Dining visible">
    <div class="neighborhood-btns">
      <div id="map-dining"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="neighborhood-listing Shopping ">
    <div class="neighborhood-btns">
      <div id="map-shopping"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="neighborhood-listing Parks ">
    <div class="neighborhood-btns">
      <div id="map-parks"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="neighborhood-listing Hospitals ">
    <div class="neighborhood-btns">
      <div id="map-hospitals"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="neighborhood-listing Colleges ">
    <div class="neighborhood-btns">
      <div id="map-colleges"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="neighborhood-listing Schools ">
    <div class="neighborhood-btns">
      <div id="map-schools"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```